# Execute procedure takes more than 3 minutes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am running one procedure where i have one table called mytable. This table contains 2 million records. When i run procedure with parameter to filter and get the data but procedure resulting data after 3 mins and returning only 12 rows. Returned data is fine but i wanted to know why procedure is taking more than 3 mins.

My procedure:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[ExampleProc]
(@Column1 VARCHAR(MAX) 
,@Column2 VARCHAR(MAX)    
,@Column3 VARCHAR(MAX)    
)
as
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  ITEM AS column1 INTO #tmpcolumn1 FROM [dbo].[Fn_SplitString](@column1, ',')   
SELECT  ITEM AS column2 INTO #tmpcolumn2 FROM [dbo].[Fn_SplitString](@column2, ',')   
SELECT  ITEM AS column3  INTO #tmpcolumn3 FROM [dbo].[Fn_SplitString](@column3, ',')  
select column1
        ,[column2]
        ,column3
        ,count(distinct memberid) Membercount 
    from myTable fact
    where EXISTS(SELECT column1 FROM #tmpcolumn1 tmpcol1 where tmpcol1.column1 = fact.column1)    
      AND EXISTS (SELECT column2 FROM #tmpcolumn2 tmpcol2 where tmpcol2.column2 = fact.column2)    
      AND EXISTS (select column3 from #tmpcolumn3 tmpcol3 where tmpcol3.column3 = fact.column3) 
      Group by column1
        ,column2
        ,column
        ,column3
END
```

I am using split function for that if parameter is sending here with separated by comma. In this function it will split the comma and insert the record as column in temporary table.

Can anyone verify this issue?

Comment: can you please paste actual execution plan ,along with schema of the tables involved and count of all the tables involved

Comment: I suspect parameter sniffing is the issue here. Can you add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I added recompile keyword before but did not get any luck in the performance.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I run the procedure with execution plan it is showing there but how i would copy and paste here it is in like uml diagram.

Comment: If you execute the statements separately, which are the ones that take the longest? If it's the last statement, you could try add an index on `#tmpcolumnX.columnX` for faster lookup in the EXISTS clauses.

Comment: try pasting the xml plan here:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: update the question with link ,schema, counts

Comment: Hi All, I have found the issue why execution time is more than 3 min. I have checked my table schema where column 3 data type is int but i am passing in stored procedure as varchar. Now i have commented column 3 in where condition and execute procedure again now execution time is 14 seconds only. Thanks for all your support.